# SSL Bypass With OkHttp3 on Rooted Device

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have used Okhttp3 library for Network Communication and have implemented SSL Pinning. Now one issue occurs on **rooted** devices for SSL bypass. I do not want to bypass SSL Pinning so that hacker can attack.

```
 this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
                    .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .followSslRedirects(false)
                    .cache(null)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0])
                    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                    .build();
```

Comment: A user of a rooted device can do whatever they want. Your primary options are either to not worry about this small set of users or not distribute an Android app. While there are some means of detecting rooted devices, so you might try to not run on them, there is a continual "arms race" between developers of root tools and those detection algorithms.

Comment: i have implemented the root detection 3rd party API (Rootbear). but root detection is also bypass-able.